# Linebreaks in Flows to populate body of contentNote

Tags: visual-workflow, html, visual-flows, contentnote, line-break

I have a flow that populates the content of a ContentNote record. i use a formula that combines values from various variables in the flow and concatenate it.This concatenated text is displayed in the body of the contentNote record.

I am facing issues in adding linebreaks between the two concatenated formulas.I have tried everything BR(),
, /n,/r,

,Substitute((text),"~","").Nothing seems to work.

Plz help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but have tried using a Text template instead of a formula?  They are meant to hold formatted data. ( https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_resources_text_template.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.18 )

Comment: You mean text template with the br tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this and the following works :). Create a Text template variable and in it put your first variable, than `<br>` (no slash) and than your second variable. If you use that as the Content of your ContentNote you get a line break in between the two varialbes

If you do use `<br/>` the flow will crash when you run it. I hope your variables don't contain anything to exotic or the flow may crash as well.

This solution also works for formula variables. (Text templates don't allow formula expressions, so we can't make the break conditional using those.) So if you want to do this just use this in a formula and assign it to the Content of the ContentNote:

```
FormulaBaseBusiness &
IF(ISBLANK(FormulaSalestarget), '', '<br>') &
FormulaSalestarget
```

Comment: Just one small doubt..The flow fetches the value to be displayed, from fields of a customobj and displays the data in the content of the contentnote .So if user doesn't edit one of the four fields used in the flow the flow adds linebreaks anyway! So it makes my content look a bit uneven. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Meena I edited the answer a bit. I think that should solve it. Happy to have helped. –

Comment: The edited answer works just fine as well!!:)

Comment: Hi Meena. I found your new question, and answered it there.